# How to define IntelliJ java breakpoint on first construction of a String

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am debugging into some pretty complex software. Some string is constructed and replaced with a modified form in several different places (the stack is pages long), but I want to find out quickly where the String with a given value is first time constructed. Conditional breakpoints seem to be tricky on this as the condition itself constructs the string I want to detect...

Any ideas? I am using IntelliJ

Comment: Strings are immutable so it’s never modified, only constructed.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid creating a new string inside the condition, you can compare the content, not the String objects. For example like this:

`Arrays.equals(str.toCharArray(), new char[]{'c', 'o', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 't'});`

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the easiest approach if your are looking for interned String (e.g. compile time constants) or JVM is performing String de-duplication (G1GC feature).

To make it trickier there were at least two changes in Java 9 that will be hard to breakpoint at:

- [JEP 280: Indify String Concatenation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280) - `InvokeDynamic` `makeConcatWithConstants` instead of `StringBuilder` when concatenating compile time constants with a `+` operator to reduce bytecode (see [this article for explanation](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/string-concatenation-java-9-untangling-invokedynamic)).
- [JEP 254: Compact Strings](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) - Latin1 strings stored as `byte[]`

If you know you are constructing your string with a `StringBuilder` I'd place a breakpoint in `StringBuilder.toString()` method were the string is hopefully constructed for the first time.

Otherwise good luck debugging through JVM internals e.g. `java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory`.